# jQuery Autosize for comment form in a colorbox?

Tags: javascript

I am struggling with jQuery Autosize for a comment form in a colorbox. I would like to pass it as a callback from script.js, but seems not to work:

```
$.colorbox.settings.onComplete = function() {
$('textarea').on('focus', function(){ $(this).autosize(); });
}
```

Is there a way to achieve having a onComplete callback for the jQuery Autosize for the comment form in the colorbox?
And I cannot achieve this functionality with bind('cbox_complete', function() neither..

```
  $(document).bind('cbox_complete', function() { 
        $('textarea.form-textarea').on('focus', function(){ $(this).autosize(); });     
  });
```

Any help will be much appreciated.